# SQL joining two tables returning error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to obtain data from two tables as shown below using one query statement, but I keep getting errors. Not sure where its going wrong.

TABLES:

```
User {ID,username,pass,gender,userdetailsID}
userdetails{ID,first_name,last_name,type,telephone,email}

                  $query = "SELECT U.username,
                        U.pass,
                        U.gender,
                        UD.first_name,
                        UD.last_name,
                        UD.type,
                        UD.telephone,
                        UD.email
                    FROM user U 
                    INNER JOIN userdetails UD
                    ON U.userdetailsID = UD.ID
                    WHERE U.ID = ?";
```

Comment: What error you are getting ? The query looks good , it must be something related to binding the value.

Comment: You have UD.mail in your select column but userdetails table contains email column.

Comment: Thanks Ninash I corrected that bust still isn't working

Comment: I am getting:  "Call to a member function execute() on a non-object"

Comment: Did you try running the query from a SQL client like phpMyAdmin?

Comment: @PrerakSola Yh it is running fine and giving the correct result

Comment: Than the problem is not in the query. May be it's in your PHP code (I guessed it fom `execute()`). You need to post that code.

Comment: @PrerakSola Thanks a lot. You are right, it was PHP not returning value to give to the prepared stmnt. Just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration:

```
userdetails{ID,first_name,last_name,type,telephone,email}
```

But in your query you're using `UD.mail` replace it with `UD.email`